# JAVA - Método para añadir aviones a una lista y que no supere los 3 aviones

Tags: java, lista

como he dicho en el título, tengo una interfaz con el siguiente método

```
List<String> anadirAvion();
```

Y tengo que hacer que dicho método agregue aviones a una lista. La lista es la siguiente:

```
private List <String> aviones;
```

**Lo que quiero saber es**: al método primero, ¿tengo que ponerle como parámetro una lista? Porque no consigo saber cómo pasar una lista por parámetros

Y dentro del método tendría que hacer que añadiera un avión (llamadio Avion1 el primero Avion2 el segundo y Avion3 el tercero si tuviera) Y que al tener 3 ya no se pudieran añadir más.

Había pensado con `aviones.add` y me faltaría poner que se llamaran como he escrito antes y que no pudiera superar 3, ¿alguna ayuda? No consigo saber cómo se hace. Muchas gracias.

Por si aclara algo, es como si estos métodos se estuvieran poniendo a un portaaviones al que se le pueda añadir hasta 3 aviones (de nombre Avion1, ...)

Comment: mmmm... tu metodo anadirAvion recibe una lista.. es como recibir cualquier otro parametro.. eso es si la lista no esta en la clase.. si esta en la clase no recibe nada.. todo eso no esta claro en la pregunta.. y luego, cual es el problema que tenes para no poner mas de 3? te fijas cuantos hay y si hay 3 no dejas agregar mas... esta como confuso que tenes y que queres...

Comment: Pues depende... Es lo más cerca que se te va a poder contestar. Tienes que ponerle como parámetro la lista? Pues depende. ¿La lista dónde está? ¿Es un miembro de la misma clase que la función? Cuál es su ámbito? Tu pregunta es demasiado general. Te recomiendo que vuelvas al manual y revises, objetos, ámbito de objetos, funciones, paso de parámetros, etc. Te hagas una idea más clara y vuelvas con las dudas que tengas. Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Para limitar el nº de elementos del arraylist, puedes extender la clase ArrayList y sobreescribir la función add, donde se compruebe el tamaño de la propia lista en cada inserción.

```
public class MiListaLimitada extends ArrayList<Object> {
  @Override
  public boolean add(Object e) {
      if (this.size() < 3) {
          return super.add(e);
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

Luego, tu lista no sería de tipo ArrayList, sino de tipo MiListaLimitada.

Para añadir un avión, te basta con añadir un elemento a la lista con el método add.

```
MiListaLimitada Aviones = new MiListaLimitada();
        Aviones.add("a");
        Aviones.add("b");
        Aviones.add("c");
        Aviones.add("d"); // No lo inserta.
        System.out.println(Aviones.size()); //Devuelve 3 -> [a, b, c]
```

En cuanto a cómo pasar una lista como parámetro de un método, supongamos que no vamos a añadir avión por avión sino todo el conjunto que tenemos en una lista(sin el método sobrescrito que controla el tamaño de las listas, para que lo veas mas claro):

Teniendo la clase Portaaviones:

```
 public class Portaaviones{

       List<String> Aviones;

       public Portaaviones(){
         aviones = new ArrayList<String>();
       }

       public void AsignarAviones(List<String> avionesParametro){
        Aviones = avionesParametro;
        }
    }
```

Podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
List<String> aviones = new ArrayList<String>();
  aviones.add("a");
  aviones.add("b");
  aviones.add("c");

Portaaviones PortaAviones1 = new Portaaviones();
 PortaAviones1.AsignarAviones(aviones);
```